# RxJS Buffer until stream is true

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs5

I want to buffer the stream, until the stream is true of a predicate:

For example, the number can be divided by five:

```
//emit value every 1 second
const oneSecondInterval = Rx.Observable.interval(1000);
//return an observable that checks if the number is divided by zero
const fiveSecondInterval = () => oneSecondInterval.filter(number => number % 5 === 0);

const bufferWhenExample = oneSecondInterval.bufferWhen(fiveSecondInterval);
//log values
const subscribe = bufferWhenExample.subscribe(val => console.log('Emitted Buffer: ', val));
```

**Output**

```
"Emitted Buffer: "
[]
"Emitted Buffer: "
[0, 1]
"Emitted Buffer: "
[2]
"Emitted Buffer: "
[3]
"Emitted Buffer: "
[4]
"Emitted Buffer: "
[5]
"Emitted Buffer: "
[6]
"Emitted Buffer: "
[7]
"Emitted Buffer: "
[8]
"Emitted Buffer: "
[9]
"Emitted Buffer: "
[10]
```

**What I want:**

```
"Emitted Buffer: "
[0]
"Emitted Buffer: "
[1,2,3,4,5]
"Emitted Buffer: "
[6,7,8,9,10]
```

But this is not working. Why?

DEMO: http://jsbin.com/durerimiju/1/edit?js,console

---

### Update

This is almost good

```
const oneSecondInterval = Rx.Observable.interval(1000);
const fiveSecondInterval = oneSecondInterval.filter(time => time % 5 === 0);
const bufferWhenExample = oneSecondInterval.buffer(fiveSecondInterval);

bufferWhenExample.subscribe(console.log)
```

The only problem is that it emits

```
[]
[0,1,2,3,4]
[5,6,7,8,9]
```

Instead I would like to have

```
[0]
[1,2,3,4,5]
[6,7,8,9,10]
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is the solution (in Typescript) that seems to work for me:

```
import { interval, OperatorFunction } from 'rxjs';
import { buffer, delay, filter, share, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

export function bufferUntil<T>(predicate:(value:T) => boolean):OperatorFunction<T, T[]>
{
    return function(source)
    {
        const share$ = source.pipe(share());
        const until$ = share$.pipe(filter(predicate), delay(0));
        return share$.pipe(buffer(until$));
    };
}

interval(1000).pipe(
    tap(console.log),
    bufferUntil(value => value % 5 === 0),
    tap(console.log)
).subscribe();
```

This results in the following output:

```
0
[0] // this emits immediately after the previous log
1
2
3
4
5
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] // this emits immediately after the previous log
6
7
8
9
10
[6, 7, 8, 9, 10] // this emits immediately after the previous log
```

If anyone has a better solution or if my implementation is dangerous or incorrect in some way, I'd love to hear it as I needed this functionality for myself.

Comment: I found issue that if you use a stream which is not an interval it just does not work. You can try: 
`from([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]).pipe(tap(console.log), bufferUntil(value => value % 5 === 0), tap(console.log)).subscribe();`

Comment: @michalc Yes, that would make sense as you are using a stream with immediate values. The original question used an interval style stream. How to do this for all scenarios is probably still a worthy question.

Answer (score 2):

The *bufferWhen* operator gets a closing observable factory function, which creates the observable on every buffer start. In your case, for every buffering iteration it creates a new interval observable that always starts with 0.

You can simply use the *buffer* operator which gets a closing observable and it will work as expected:

```
const oneSecondInterval = Rx.Observable.interval(1000);
const fiveSecondInterval = oneSecondInterval.filter((number) => number % 5 === 0);
oneSecondInterval.buffer(fiveSecondInterval);
```

I eddited your jsbin [here](http://jsbin.com/wazavilusa/1/edit?js,console)

Comment: This is almost good. My only problem is that I would like to have `[0]` at first, and `[1,2,3,4,5]` second and not `[]` first and `[0,1,2,3,4]` second

Comment: It is a synchronization issue with the first closing signal. This will ensure that the closing observable emits only after the source observable.
const bufferExample = oneSecondInterval.buffer(fiveSecondInterval.delay(0));

http://jsbin.com/nulizacele/edit?js,console

Answer (score 1):

The `interval` observable doesn't emit a count of the number of times it has gone off, it just emits `undefined`. So when you do `.filter(number => number % 5 === 0)`, the predicate is always returning false.

To keep a count of how many values have been emitted, you can use the [.scan operator](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/scan.html):

```
const fiveSecondInterval = () => 
    oneSecondInterval
        .scan(count => count + 1, 0)
        .filter(count => count % 5 === 0);
```

Comment: Very good answer! I would only add that a simple ` oneSecondInterval.do(x => console.info(x)).filter(number => number % 5 === 0)` helped diagnose the issue with the `.filter` behavior.

Comment: I dont understand. If I do `Rx.Observable.interval(1000).subscribe(console.log)`, it emits increasing numbers. What is emitting undefined?

Comment: Ah, you're right, i didn't have the reason correct. What's happening is that the interval emits a 0, which passes the filter (0 % 5 === 0). Since it passed the filter, bufferWhen emits whatever it has, and then resubscribes to fiveSecondInterval. When it resubscribes, that causes it to emit a 0 again, and then again, and again. The reason my "fix" worked was because i was starting at 1, so it would have to count up to 5 before the filter would pass it. You can fix your code by doing `.filter(count => count % 5 === 4)`, which will force it to count from 0 to 4 before starting over.

Answer (score 0):

Addressing the issue raised by @michalc in the comments to [@TroyWeber's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60518289/2427596).

Here's a pretty simple function that (I believe) works in all cases. It doesn't do anything fancy or leverage other operators, but gets the job done!

```js
import { from, Observable, type OperatorFunction } from 'rxjs'

function bufferUntil<T>(predicate: (value: T) => boolean): OperatorFunction<T, T[]> {
  return (source: Observable<T>) => new Observable<T[]>(observer => {
    let buffer: T[] = []

    return source.subscribe({
      next(value) {
        buffer.push(value)

        if (predicate(value)) {
          observer.next(buffer)
          buffer = []
        }
      },
      error(err) { observer.error(err) },
      complete() { observer.complete() },
    })
  })
}

from([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]).pipe(
  bufferUntil(n => n % 5 === 0),
).subscribe(console.log)
```